# ios handle pushnotification in background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to save a push notification that arrives when the application is in background state. I know about

`-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`

This delegate method is called when the app is in foreground or background (if the user just clicks on the received notification).

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

This method is called only once when the app starts.

What if the user doesn't click on the notification? How can I save the data of that notification in the database of my app in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case, you can't save the data in the 'database of [your] app'; instead you save the data in the database on your server, which is where the PushNotification was generated in the first place.  Then, when your App is started, it queries your database to get the notification data.

Comment: You can set the badge count with the notification, and only if the count is greater than zero, query the server.

Comment: thanx @GoZoner Your Answer is also valuable for me.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Both answer is helpful for me because first one solve my confusion and second one give me the answer how to handle push when app is in background state. I don't have choice other wise I selected both solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the user doesn't click on the notification, you can't save that data.
Even if the user opens the app by tapping its launch icon the app won't receive that data.

Also remember the design of notification is to deliver small payload to alert the user.
 Once the users starts the app, the app can download the real data you want to save.

Comment: If the user doesn't tap on the notification, your app still gets the notification as long as your app is running, though you can't process it until your app becomes active. This changes in iOS7. I believe your app will be able to process the notification even when the app isn't active (but is running in the background).

Comment: @MarcusAdams do you know of any docs/resources you can direct us to that explains how to get this remote push notification data in the background in iOS7?