# How can I store Push Notification alert message in UserDefault?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, push-notification, nsuserdefaults

I want to build an app that I can receive push notification and save inside client device for limit 25 Notification. If application running and may not running. How can I stored PushNotification alert message?. If app running that time arrived Notification alert message stored in UserDefault but when app in background or Inactive state that time not stored Notification alert message in UserDefault. I want to know that I need to use UserDefault or CoreData to store the Push Notification message inside client app or not? If it is not, what should I use? I really need a hand to pick me up.

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot process the push notification without open it. My advise, keep the notifications send to each devices on your server instead

Comment: @h44f33z any other way can i stored arrived notification in UserDefualt or CoreDate?

Comment: For me, its not about "where" to save it, but the issue here is you cannot check the push notification unless you open the received notification. Also, if you open one of three notifications(let say), you only can get the one that you opened, the rest wont get the contents

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067955/ios-handle-pushnotification-in-background and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137304/ios-apns-not-received-in-background-mode?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

STEP 1:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
     {
         requestUserPermissions(application: application)
         if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject]
            {
                let info : NSDictionary! = notification as NSDictionary
                if info != nil
                {
                    getDataFromNotification(userInfo: info as! [AnyHashable : Any])
                    Alert.showAlert((self.window?.rootViewController)!, message: "App is terminated", strtitle: "Notification")
                }
            }
            return true
    }
```

STEP 2:

```
func requestUserPermissions(application: UIApplication)
    {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
        {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound])
            {
                (granted, error) in

                if( !(error != nil) )
                {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
                // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
            }

        }
        else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            if (!application.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)
            {
                application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
```

STEP 3:

```
@objc(userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:) @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
 {

       print("Userinfo1 \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
        getDataFromNotification(userInfo: response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
        Alert.showAlert((self.window?.rootViewController)!, message: "I am in Background", strtitle: "Notification")
    }
      @objc(userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:) @available(iOS 10.0, *)
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
        {
           print("Userinfo2 \(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
            getDataFromNotification(userInfo: notification.request.content.userInfo)
            Alert.showAlert((self.window?.rootViewController)!, message: "I am in forground", strtitle: "Notification")
        }
```

STEP 4:

```
func getDataFromNotification(userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any])
    {
        let info : NSDictionary! = userInfo as NSDictionary

        if info != nil
        {
            if let aps = info["aps"] as? NSDictionary
            {
               if let resultsDict =  aps as? [String:AnyObject]
             {
                for _ in resultsDict
               {
                let str = dictCleanData.value(forKey: "alert")!
                let time = dictCleanData.value(forKey: "day")!

                let dict = ["msg" : str, "time": time]

                UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "dict")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                  }
             }
           }
     }
}
```

STEP 5: TO check saved data on Other view controller

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
 {
        super.viewDidLoad()

           if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "dict") != nil
          {
             let dict : NSDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "dict") as! NSDictionary

               arr_Veges.add(dict)

               if  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "arr_Veges") != nil
               {
                  let arr = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "arr_Veges") as! NSArray

                  for oldObj in arr
                  {
                    arr_Veges.add(oldObj)
                  }
               }

               UserDefaults.standard.set(arr_Veges, forKey: "arr_Veges")
               UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
}
```

Comment: Application is not running than Notification data is not stored in UserDefault.

Comment: What are you trying to say? Please explain. In order to store data you have to run application. UserDefault is used to store your data. i.e with use of UserDefaults you are able to see your previous and current data.

Comment: Or, If I understand you are talking about when the app is in background or terminate. Is it?

Comment: Yes. When app in background or terminate than Notification data not stored.

Comment: This Code write inside  AppDelegate := if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: AnyObject] {
            if let alertDict = remoteNotification["aps"] as? [AnyHashable: AnyObject] {
                if let alert = alertDict["alert"] {
                    if let body = alert["body"] as? String {
                        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(body, forKey: "Body")
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Above code write inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate

Comment: Also same code write work perfect  inside didReceiveRemoteNotification of AppDelegate.

Comment: Dear when receive Notification Inactive state of application and Launch application with debug mode break point not going inside IF(if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: AnyObject]) condition. Break point not going inside if condition How we can store Pushnotification body  in UserDefault

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130114/discussion-between-amanpreet-and-iparesh).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can use `NSUserDefaults` to store user related information. Push Notifications in your case. However, just a thought, you can simple append the notifications to local storage or a `txt` file on user device and remove the element as user accesses it.

But this will only work when user is using the app. In case you want to make this work even when the app is not working, you need to make a backend and store these data in some kind of cloud database. You can extract the records from data and push again to `NSUserDefaults` or local `txt` file when the app is turned on again.