# Why I'm not able to handle received push notifications in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I already imported

```
import UserNotifications
```

and connected delegate:

```
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
```

and set delegates as self:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
```

and finally I have these functions:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    //Handle the notification
    print("User Info = ",notification.request.content.userInfo)
    completionHandler([.Alert, .Badge, .Sound])
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    //Handle the notification
    print("User Info = ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
```

but I do not get on my log any prints when I'm testing on a real device and in the background mode.

What is the problem?

```
internal func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {        
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}
```

Comment: You must have to debug your code using breakpoint. If this method didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called. Then you have to check backend.

Comment: it debugs only if I'm in app. But when I'm in the background mode, I receive the notification, but cannot handle it @Amanpreet

Comment: Please check the answer below. And why are you use two methods of "didReceiveRemoteNotification" ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try with following code. You just need to save data.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> ())
{
     let info : NSDictionary! = userInfo as! NSDictionary

     if info != nil
      {
          let aps = info["aps"] as? NSDictionary
          UserDefaults.standard.set(aps, forKey: "aps")
       }
   }
```

And use the user defaults where you want to use.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035878/how-can-i-store-push-notification-alert-message-in-userdefault/41037919#41037919

Comment: surely you must call the completion handle3r ??

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  let info = userInfo as! [String : AnyObject]
  let aps = info["aps"] as? NSDictionary
  print(aps)
 }
```