# Push notification does not work in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, apple-push-notifications

Initial we import the `UserNotifications` framework 
and we initialize the delegate method in `AppDelegate.swift` class

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *){

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if (granted)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
            else{
                //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
            }
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035878/how-can-i-store-push-notification-alert-message-in-userdefault/41037919#41037919

Answer (score -1):

Please check the "**Push Notification**" switch under `Target > Capabilities`:

> Turn it ON