# Firebase iOS receive data from push notification

Tags: swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I am currently attempting to send a notification through firebase to iOS which contains data which I would like to save to a variable.

My server is pushing a notification which my phone receives, and the notification contains `topic_name, message_body, data_message, sound`. All of which work, although I am confused as to how I can access the data. Essentially, I want to save the sent data to a variable.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: read data from the received notification payload. can you clear the concept, you want save the data in foreground and back ground

Comment: might be help you this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035878/how-can-i-store-push-notification-alert-message-in-userdefault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

payload like this

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Notification with custom payload!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "content-available" : 1
    },
     "data" :{
        "title" : "Game Request",
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
     }
}
```

Read the payload data

```
@available(iOS 10, *)

    extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

              if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary
             {
                let alert = aps["alert"]as? NSString
                let badge = aps["badge"] as? Int
             }
          completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you actually have the data you can pass it around in your code in many ways. One way is to post a notification with the data which the class/object responsible for using the data can listen to. The best solution to use sort of depends on how your app is structured...

Comment: My question is how do I access the data? Ex. If I sent `"data": "foo"`, how would I access `"foo"` within swift (considering I am using firebase to send/receive the notifications)?