# How to read custom data sent in push notification using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to retrieve "data" which I sent in push notification using Firebase in iOS Application(Swift)

here is the code which I used to send notification :

```
{
   "to": "dWB537Nz1GA:APA91bHIjJ5....",
   "data":
   {
      "message": "Offer!",
      "mediaUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG"
   },
   "notification":
   {
      "body": "Enter your message",
      "sound": "default"
   }
}
```

I implemented only one method to read data from notification :

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    //checked where I can get custom data which I sent but no success
    let notification =  response.notification.request.content.body

    print("Notification recived content:\(response.notification.request.content)")
    print("userNotificationCenter : didReceive response body : \(notification)")
    print("userNotificationCenter : didReceive response user info : \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    print("userNotificationCenter : response : \(response)")


    completionHandler()
}
```

Checked in above method where I can get custom data which I sent but no success

I searched for solution at so many places but no success. Please help me to retrieve custom data.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325216/firebase-ios-receive-data-from-push-notification/50326781#50326781

Answer (score 1):

I'm using like this in swift side:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    if let menu = userInfo["Menu"] as? NSString {
        print(menu)
    }

    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

here is the code which I used to send notification :

```
{
   "to": "/topics/....",
   "data":
   {
      "Menu": "Summary"
   },
   "notification":
   {
      "title": "Header",
      "text": "Message",
      "sound": "default"
   }
}
```